# Captcha called on HTTP only

Tags: checkout, ssl, https, secure, captcha

I have a Magento site that has recently begun to stop showing the captcha forms. Also, some browsers (Safari) are refusing to show that my checkout page is secure because, even though the rest of the page's content is through SSL, the captcha is still being called from http and not https.

The error I get is:

> [Warning] The page at [my site url] ran insecure content from http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js. (onepage, line 51, x2)

The offending code output appears as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if((DRjQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(DRjQuery.browser.version, 10) != 7) || !DRjQuery.browser.msie) {
                document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js'><\/script>");
    }
</script>
```

How do I get Magento to use https for captcha?

Where can I find the code (above) where Magento outputs the http so that I can change it to https?

Comment: Do you have that hard coded to http?

Comment: @brentwpeterson I do not recall doing so. The offending code output on the page is: <script type="text/javascript">
        if((DRjQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(DRjQuery.browser.version, 10) != 7) || !DRjQuery.browser.msie) {
                    document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js'><\/script>");
        }
    </script>

Comment: simple extension https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included the `http://` protocol for the link, which is therefore making an unsecured request. Since google offer support for both the `http://` and `https://` protocols via the same URL, you can simply use the relative protocol `//` to make the browser use the current pages protocol.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if((DRjQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(DRjQuery.browser.version, 10) != 7) || !DRjQuery.browser.msie) {
            document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='//www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js'><\/script>");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: right. But where can I access this code? I have looked everywhere. Would you happen to know which file it would be in?

Comment: To my knowledge recaptcha has never been a part of core Magento, so where it exists will depend on the implementation you're using. In the Fontis module for example, it appears to be in `app/code/community/Fontis/Recaptcha/Helper/Data.php`.

Comment: To my knowledge we are not using any extension for the Captcha. I see that we have the file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Helper/Data.php but the incorrect http URL is not there. Where can it be?

Comment: `Mage_Captcha` is not related to recaptcha. As stated, I don't believe it's in core, so I can't help with where. Whichever module adds jQuery as DRjQuery is presumably the source.

Comment: success!!! You were right! It was an extension from MageWorkshop called Detailed Review (the 'DR' you hinted to). They must have hardcoded the 'http' in by mistake... Thank you so much!!